# How to create excel add-in (excel 2003 or previous version) package with activeX dll?

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, excel-2003

I am new to excel add-in prgramming and I am having a existing excel add-in project need to modify.

The plug-in has 2 parts, one is programmed in VB and compiled into a ActiveX DLL file, the other part is inside the excel as an add-in.

I already modified the source code of the DLL and recompiled a new DLL, but I don't know what is the correct way to re-package the 2 parts into one excel add-in package and give to my colleagues.

I tried to remove the reference to old DLL from excel, but it seems I could not do that, it will always be there and I can't really remove it.

This add-in is for excel 2003 or previous version, not for excel 2007.

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to DLL Hell!

You'll have to remove the reference to the old dll.

Have a look at: [regsvr32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32)

1. Close Excel
2. Click Start / Run / cmd
3. Type `regsvr32 /u [path of old dll]/[filename]`
4. Then `regsvr32 [path of new dll]/[filename]`

Eg:
 `regsvr32 /u c:\windows\system32\file.dll`

You can add /q to hide all messages

How do you repackage it for your colleagues?  There are multiple ways.  Create a bat file and email it, put it as part of the logon script.  Or go to each workstation and manually do it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I will do the test tomorrow morning based on this. Thanks again!