# excel: mid: can't find project or library

Tags: excel, vba

for some reason in my VBA code in excel, when it gets to a line of code where i am using `mid` it says can't find project or library. what does this mean?

Comment: missing: structure manager activex control module, i cannot uncheck it: can't remove because in use, but the macro is stopped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go old skool and remove the structure manager activex control.

I gave similar instructions on how to do this are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575863/how-to-create-excel-add-in-excel-2003-or-previous-version-package-with-activex/1587003#1587003)!

Have a look at: [regsvr32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575863/how-to-create-excel-add-in-excel-2003-or-previous-version-package-with-activex/1587003#1587003)

1. Close Excel
2. Click Start / Run / cmd
3. Type `regsvr32 /u [path of old dll]/[filename]`

Eg:
 `regsvr32 /u c:\windows\system32\file.dll`

(You can add /q to hide all messages)

Good luck!

Answer (score 19):

This is due some problem with references within VBA in your workbook.

In the VBA editor, go to 'Tools-> References'. There you would find a reference with 'MISSING:' in front. Uncheck that and your problem should be fixed.

If the missing reference was something like 'Visual Basic for Application' or 'Microsoft Office Object library, you should look for a reference that has no 'MISSING:' text and select this.

Comment: missing: structure manager activex control module, i cannot uncheck it: can't remove because in use, but the macro is stopped!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. This does the job much more efficiently than the above.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the VBA editor (e.g. by using ALT-F11).

Click on Tools->References

If any references are marked MISSING then correct those missing references. This should fix your problem.

Comment: missing: structure manager activex control module, i cannot uncheck it: can't remove because in use, but the macro is stopped!

Comment: not sure how it can be in use while at the same time also missing. is the code in "break mode" or "stopped"? you probably need to "stop" code execution entirely then try and uncheck

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any references to *any* library that is missing?

I've found that any bad reference -- even when not used in the code -- can throw the entire system off, so that even built-in functions are mapped wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"Click on Tools->References
If any references are marked MISSING then correct those missing references. This should fix your problem."

It solved my problem (Left function throwing error "can't find project or library).