# I get compile error when create new instance of file system object

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

When I try to run this code, I get an error like this

> Compile error
>   Can't find a project or library.

```
Public FSO As New FileSystemObject

Sub DiskSpace()
    Dim drv As Drive
    Dim Space As Double
    Set drv = FSO.GetDrive("C:") ' Creating the the Drive object

    Space = drv.FreeSpace
    Space = Space / 1073741824 'converting bytes to GB
    Space = WorksheetFunction.Round(Space, 2) ' Rounding

    MsgBox "C: has free space = " & Space & " GB"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime?

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers Failure to set a reference would give a different error.  Try it.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for quick replies.
I was able to solve the problem.

I had to change 2 lines as follows. But can't understand why.

     Public FSO As New scripting.FileSystemObject

     Dim drv As scripting.Drive

Comment: @RonRosenfeld.  I believe Excel Developers is correct.  I created a new workbook and imported coderH's code.  It failed as reported.  I then set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and the code displayed a message box  giving the free space on drive C:

Comment: `scripting.` tells the compiler where to look for the definitions of `FileSystemObject` and `Drive`.  This avoids the need for a reference.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Interesting.  When I copied coderH's code and ran it, without setting the reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, I get "Compile Error, User-defined type not defined"

Comment: @TonyDallimore But I got error when I have set the reference. This may be excel version related error. I'm using excel 2013 single language version.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  Strange.  I have got "User-defined type not defined" in the past when I forgot to set the reference.  I do not remember being told it was a "Compile Error" though.  Why should we get different error messages for the same error?  There must be some other subtle difference between our installations.  Not sure I am interested enough to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, otherwise the error would be something like User defined type not defined.

In the VBA Editor, go to Tools/References and look for a Reference with MISSING.  Uncheck that and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
I was able to solve the problem.

I had to change 2 lines as follows. But can't understand why.

Public FSO As New scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim drv As scripting.Drive

Comment: Do you know why I need to add scripting at the beginning?

Comment: @coderH If you do not have the reference set, then your code doesn't understand `Drive`.  With the reference, you should not need it.  Did you have any MISSING references in the list?

Comment: Yes I have one missing reference to microsoft office web components 11.0

Comment: Is it unchecked?

Comment: It is checked. I tried to remove tick. But it didn't allow. I get following message.

_"Can't remove control or reference: in use"_

However I used this same code in new workbook. Then it worked.

Comment: @coderH Probably the reference is either not missing or not checked in the new workbook.  You might be able to remove the reference in your existing file with the procedure shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923516/excel-mid-cant-find-project-or-library). You should be able to add it back by browsing to the correct dll file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. In the VBE, click on Tools, References, then scroll down to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and tick the box next to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have done it already. But this was not the reason.